# Data driven mobile application using python-programming newbie

Tags: python, leaflet, geojson, mobile-application

I am studying survey engineering and for my thesis i will be developing a mobile app using python. The app will be used to help in the completion of the  national cadastre and its main purpose will be to Promote volunteering through gamifying the process of collecting geodata. The app will be using a wms basemap provided by the cadastre's services and it will also allow the users to create layers and draw polygons and lines that will be submitted to a database. Achievements and a leaderboard will be a part of the app(e.g a leaderboard based on the number of polygons provided by the users).

The thing is that my python skills are very limited to just being able to solve some problems in sites like hackerrankm so i have no prior experience to app development and it would be very helpful if someone with some experience would be in the position to guide me even for my very first steps in this process.

All Information is appreciated. I have searched for some packages to begin with like leaflet and im experimenting with it but i really do not know how to implement an editor or anything actually im still researching.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your app sounds cool.  But this question is not really appropriate for this site.  SO is geared towards specific programming questions / problems / bugs, and this is more of a "where do I get started" question.  There are lots of tutorials on leaflet, editing shapes and GIS data in leaflet, etc.  I recommend you spend some time learning basics.  You may also consider doing this with ArcGIS, which is more python-oriented, and already has a [publicly editable featurelayer](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/public-editable-feature-layers/m-p/25374) concept.

Comment: thank for your reply. ESRI already has a similar application which is arcgis collector and i and i wanted to do something similar but add the gamification aspect to it. I am doing my research and im actually about to start experimenting with leaflet i just did a python course to refresh my memory. If it is against the rules feel free to delete my question and thank you for sharing the ediaplt featurelayer with me!

Comment: Moreover I am not sure python is the best choice for developing mobile applications. You should also take into account that drawing shapes on a map in a mobile device is not the most convenient thing to do from a UX perspective. A web app would be more appropriate to do so or even a tablet device. Once you conquer the basics perhaps you might get some advice from a professor and break things down. When you do that you can come back here and ask specific technical questions.

Comment: I know that python is not the best choice! i chose it because of the easy to read and write syntax it has! And also i would choose a web app over a mobile application but thats what i was asked to do.. so i will do my best to go through with it

Comment: Indeed python is the most beginner friendly language but I am not sure its mobile community is as large as in other mobile technologies out there at the moment. Anyways it is always your choice and best of luck to your thesis.